# RN checkbox as card and multi select

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've to select one or two cards from a list of cards , where on tap of each card / checkbox , that card gets highlighted (and is selected). Each card has checkbox on it, which shows that particular card through which selection is made. You can re-tap on the same checkbox to unselect it.

I'm pretty new to react native and confused how to achieve this functionality. Here's the code for reference.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {View, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import { Container, Content, ListItem, CheckBox, Text, Body } from 'native-base';

export default class Career extends Component {
    topics = ['abc','def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
  render() {
    const extract = this.topics.map((topic, i) => {
        return(
            <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
             <Image style={{width:50, height:50}} source={require('../../assets/images/idcLogo.png')}/>
             <CheckBox checked={false}></CheckBox>
             <Text>{topic}</Text>
         </View>
        )
    });
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          {extract}
          </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cardContainer: {
        borderRadius:5,
        borderColor:"#ccc",
        borderWidth:2,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        width:'50%',
        margin:5
    },
    mainContainer:{
        justifyContent:'center',
        width:'100%',
        alignItems:'center',
        flex:1
    }
})
```

Please let me know if this you need any other information on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the `<View style={styles.cardContainer}></View>` into `<TouchableOpacity style={styles.cardContainer}>` then I'll add a function to monitor the changes of the checked status for the button.

1. I'll add this function before the render function

`handleOnTap = (topic) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ [topic]: !prevState[topic], });
}`

2. `<Checkbox onPress={() => this.handleOnTap(topic)} checked={!!this.state[topic]} />`
3. Don't forget to add a key generating elements via this.topics.map; `<TouchableOpacity style={styles.cardContainer} key={`topic-${i}`}>`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks @Harvey, this works pretty well. Also I had one followup question, how do I limit the amount of checkboxes being checked and also how to fetch the value which has been checked.

Comment: @KaranTewari an easy way to limit the amount of checkboxes checked is adding a counter that gets incremented or decremented depending on the new state of a checkbox.